# Getting "com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed" Exception?

Tags: android, exception

When I run application it show me "com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed" Exception.

Any body have any idea why this is occurring and how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just reset the adb(In ur eclipse go to DDMS perspective. In devices tab click on the down arrow-> reset adb).[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your adb server might have died. Try restarting it:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Tanks..but i didn't face same problem again..once i restart system again.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and tried a variety of things.  Not sure exactly which one solved it.

I tried "adb kill-server and adb start-server" and that did nothing.  I was able to adb shell into my device and use logcat from terminal, but Eclipse would still not work.

Tried restarting just Eclipse and that did nothing.

Rebooted computer and rebooted phone.  Went into Settings->Applications->Development and Turned Debugging off and then back on.  Then it showed up correctly in Eclipse and I can see the logcat.