# error when running the project and stopped the project unexpectedly

Tags: android

I had this error when runing the Android project:

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found  at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)    at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
>     at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)   at
>   com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

and when I checked the code I reached that when I commented this code block:

```
public class ElarabyGroup extends Activity {
    private String TAG ;
    private String SENDER_ID = "123456789123";
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }
```

The error finished but I cannot use GCM on my project.
Please help.

Comment: Just try this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7115455/940096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restart your eclipse and adb.

please refer this `http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the adb(In ur eclipse go to DDMS perspective. In devices tab click on the down arrow-> reset adb).
[image]